# Hamburger menu not working after click on the sub menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

Hope you are enjoying:)
I need little help

My website is working fine but on sub menu pages the hamburger menus not showing up at all. its showing completely fine on all the other pages but on every sub menu page its gone..

http://packsmartinc.com/market-segment/specialty-print-finishing-solutions/
(this is the one of my sub menu page)

Please view my case & let me know.

Thanks,
Omer

Comment: Could we see your code so that we can solve this problem?

Comment: Hey Danny, It's a WordPress website, how can I sent you the code ?? Please give me your email so I can sent you my test admin credentials.

Comment: @DannyV one of my friend told me that this is what your pages throw the error. check if you understand something from this.

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'selectize' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectize' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://packsmartinc.com/wp-content/themes/packsmartinc/js/app.js?ver=1.0.0:14145:54)
    at l (http://packsmartinc.com/wp-content/themes/packsmartinc/js/app.js?ver=1.0.0:1595:63)
    at m (http://packsmartinc.com/wp-content/themes/packsmartinc/js/app.js?ver=1.0.0:1601:53) undefined
fbevents.js:24 Facebook Pixel Error: Error: Duplicate Pixel ID: 249398855589158

Comment: paste code in stackoverflow

Comment: @DannyV please see the code below in answer

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Responsive Menu */
.menu-other-style .menu-item:not(.current-menu-item) {
    display: none;
}
.menu-other-style .current-menu-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.menu-other-style .current-menu-item::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-feature-settings: normal;
    font-kerning: auto;
    font-language-override: normal;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-synthesis: weight style;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 30%;
}
.menu-other-style .current-menu-item::before {
    content: "\f054";
}     
.menu-other-style .current-menu-item.open::before {
    content: "\f078";
}

.menu-other-style .current-menu-item a {
    padding: 20px;
}
.menu-other-style .current-menu-item a br {
    display: none;
}

.mobi-submenu-two {
    margin-top: 0;
    display: none;
}
.mobi-submenu-two .menu-item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.mobi-submenu-two .menu-item a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
@media (max-width: 1350px) {

}


---------------------------------------  

.navi--top > li {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
.navi--top > li > a {
  height: 100%;
}
.navi--top > li.current-menu-item > a {
  background-color: #95050a;
}
.navi--top > li .sub-menu {
  background: #d31f26 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0 0;
  width: 350px;
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
.navi--top > li .sub-menu li:hover .sub-menu,
.navi--top > li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
.navi--top > li .sub-menu li {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.navi--top > li .sub-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
  display: block;
}
.navi--top > li .sub-menu li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(149, 5, 10, 0.7);
}
.sub-menu > li > .sub-menu {
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
  border-top: 0;
  width: 450px;
}
```